# FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully

Tags: android-studio, tensorflow, android-ndk, bazel

I tried to build tensorflow demo in Android Studio 3.1.1 with ndk version 14.1.3816874 , Android SDK platform-tool version 27.0.1 , Android SDK tool 26.1.1 , SDK Build-Tools 28 rc-1 , and Bazel 0.11.1-homebrew

run the terminal command : bazel build thru terminal but got the error below

```
$ bazel build //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo
```

[image: android studio tensorflow build error thru bazel build command in terminal]

I also tried to run the build thru build.gradle - bazel but still got an error.

> Process 'command '/usr/local/bin/bazel'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

[image: android studio tensorflow build error thru build.gradle]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Bazel doesn't know where `@androidndk` is.

Please go to the `WORKSPACE` files and [make sure the following lines are not commented out](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/63c6562df68ade3a03481874a71b536a4e02b6f5/WORKSPACE#L25):

```
# Uncomment and update the paths in these entries to build the Android demo.
android_sdk_repository(
    name = "androidsdk",
    api_level = 23,
    # Ensure that you have the build_tools_version below installed in the
    # SDK manager as it updates periodically.
    build_tools_version = "26.0.1",
    # Replace with path to Android SDK on your system
    path = "<PATH_TO_SDK>",
)

android_ndk_repository(
    name="androidndk",
    path="<PATH_TO_NDK>",
    # This needs to be 14 or higher to compile TensorFlow.
    # Please specify API level to >= 21 to build for 64-bit
    # archtectures or the Android NDK will automatically select biggest
    # API level that it supports without notice.
    # Note that the NDK version is not the API level.
    api_level=14
)
```